# C Programming getting input

Tags: c, algorithm

How do I constantly get user input (strings) until enter is pressed in C just like `string` class in C++?

I don't know the input size so I can't declare a variable of fixed size or even I can't allocate memory dynamically using `malloc()` or `calloc()`.

Is there any way to implement this as a separate function?

Comment: `while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)`, and `realloc()` exponentially.

Comment: @zaibis First, you **did** write "as you are on windows OS". Then you have corrected "as" to "if" after my comment. Don't pretend you didn't make a mistake whereas you did.

Comment: You can also use a linked list of buffer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use exponential storage expansion:

```
char *read_a_line(void)
{
    size_t alloc_size = LINE_MAX;
    size_t len = 0;

    char *buf = malloc(LINE_MAX); // should be good for most, euh, *lines*...
    if (!buf)
       abort();

    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        if (len >= alloc_size) {
            alloc_size <<= 1;
            char *tmp = realloc(buf, alloc_size);
            if (!tmp)
                abort(); // or whatever

            buf = tmp;
        }

        buf[len++] = c;
    }

    if (len >= alloc_size) {
        alloc_size++;
        char *tmp = realloc(buf, alloc_size);
        if (!tmp)
            abort(); // or whatever

        buf = tmp;
    }

    buf[len] = 0;
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Just a comment on style: You might want to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @thejh Sure. But no way I'm writing a separate 4-line `extend_buffer()` function in a SO answer. I'm doing that in real life, though, when there's stuff needed to be done along with reallocation.

Comment: Have a look at my answer – you just need to change the first `len >= alloc_size` to `len >= alloc_size-1` and you can drop the second block for extending the buffer.

Answer (score 7):

As H2CO3 said, you should allocate a buffer with `malloc()`, then resize it with `realloc()` whenever it fills up. Like this:

```
size_t bufsize = 256;
size_t buf_used = 0;
int c;
char *buf = malloc(bufsize);
if (buf == NULL) { /* error handling here */ }
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
  if (c == '\n') break;
  if (buf_used == bufsize-1) {
    bufsize *= 2;
    buf = realloc(buf, bufsize);
    if (buf == NULL) { /* error handling here */ }
  }
  buf[buf_used++] = c;
}
buf[buf_used] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, you have little choice: If you want to input a string of unbounded length, have to use allocations in a loop. Whether you use `realloc()` or a linked list of buffers, it comes down to reading (usually through `fgets()`), reading some more, and so on until the buffer you've just read contains a `\n`.

Then, depending on the method, you either already have a contiguous buffer (the `realloc` method) or just need to concatenate them all (the linked list method). Then you can return.

If you're lucky, your platform comes with the extension function [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) that does the realloc method for you. If not, you'll have to write it yourself.